Are there any flutter library to support bluetooth printing on Bixolon spp-R410 thermal printer with 4 inch (112mm) paper?
I am working on a project which requires printing with Bixolon spp-R410 printer, a 4 inch 112mm printing type. I'm Using flutter library - flutter_bluetooth_printer: ^2.17.1 , which supports upto 80mm. The receipt printed occupies 3/4 of the paper from left to right. Is there a way to use the full size of the paper(112mm) ? Or is there any flutter library that fully support the specified printer ?
The flutter library that i used didn't support 112mm paper size

you can try this  https://pub.dev/packages/bx_btprinter or https://medium.com/@nathanprodd/integrating-the-bixolon-sdk-into-a-flutter-project-7cdfb569a424
